# CefShap - How can I inject a double click into the webpage via C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have an application based on CefSharp v83.4.20 and try to inject a double click from the C# code. This happens for both, Winform and WPF.

This is the used Html for testing:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; z-index: 100; background: rgb(0, 0, 0); left: 100px; top: 100px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
  elem.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    console.log('mousedown');
  });

  elem.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    console.log('mouseup');
  });

  elem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('click');
  });

  elem.addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
    // this never gets called when injecting two clicks, but works when manually double clicking
    console.log('doubleclicked');
   });
</script>
```

I can easily inject clicks to the Html from the C# code like this:

```
int x = 150;
int y = 150;
var host = chromeBrowserInstance.GetBrowser().GetHost();

host.SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 0, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
host.SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 0, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton);
```

But how can i inject a double click?
Simple sending two clicks as shown above fails:

```
int x = 150;
int y = 150;
var host = chromeBrowserInstance.GetBrowser().GetHost();

host.SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 0, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
host.SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 0, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton);

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

host.SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 0, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
host.SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 0, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton);
```

This gives following output (missing the expected 'doubleclicked'):

```
mousedown
mouseup
click
mousedown
mouseup
click
```

When double clicking manually the expected 'doubleclicked' appears:

```
mousedown
mouseup
click
mousedown
mouseup
click
doubleclicked
```

I tried to adjust timings, but nothing helped. Any ideas how to inject a working double click?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the input, I tried:

```
MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent(150, 150, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton);
bool mouseup = true;
int clickCount = 2;

host.SendMouseClickEvent(
    me,
    MouseButtonType.Left,
    mouseup,
    clickCount
);
```

But whatever I set for `clickCount` (even 0) it only produces a single mouseup /
mousedown event. 
After adding random text to the body I found, that using the above method with
`clickCount` being either 2 or 3 and `mouseup = true` the text in the body gets
highlighted just like when double/triple clicking it manually. 
So it works somehow, but does not produce the expected events.

Comment: Try using http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_SendMouseClickEvent.htm instead and specifying a click count

Comment: Does the WPF example included in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample work as expected? It uses the mouse functions internally.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use Winforms for testing. But testing the same code with the MinimalExample WPF version produces the exact same results.

Comment: Did you load your html in the WPF example and use the mouse? The WPF version uses those methods internally,  if it works in the WPF example you can add some logging to workout the calls you need.

Answer (score 2):

This does a double click and makes the `dblclick` event fire:

```
public void double_click(int x, int y) {
    var host = browser.GetHost();

    // first click            
    host.SendMouseClickEvent(
        x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 1, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton
    );

    host.SendMouseClickEvent(
        x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 1, CefEventFlags.None
    );

    // second click
    host.SendMouseClickEvent( 
        x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 2, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton
    );

    host.SendMouseClickEvent(
        x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 1, CefEventFlags.None
    );            
}
```

After doing some logging in `CefSharp.WPF.ChromiumWebBrowser.cs` as proposed by amaitland I found out why the above fails:
I misinterpreted the `count` parameter by **thinking** it would be the number of clicks that will be executed. **But in reality** it is the index of the current event in a series of events.
For example the `count` parameter of the third `SendMouseClickEvent` is `2` so that cef knows that the second and third event belong together.